# HTML5 Sound Recording in Firefox

Tags: html, webrtc

I have been trying to record audio through browsers using HTML5 and was successful in doing that in chrome. I wanted to know if there was any such API that supports audio recording in firefox. I tried executing the code used in chrome in firefox but was not able to since firefox does not support AudioContext. I was trying other features using the WebRTC with a few tweaks but nothing seems to be working. Is it that firefox does not support such recording or am I on the wrong way?
My Code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
navigator.getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                       navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.msGetUserMedia);

navigator.getMedia (

   // constraints
   {
      audio: true
   },

   // successCallback
   function(localMediaStream) {
      var video = document.querySelector('audio');
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
      video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
         //I do my recording here..
      };
   },

   // errorCallback
   function(err) {
    console.log("The following error occured: " + err);
   }

);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

**`MediaRecorder API`** has been landed in Firefox **nightlies** (currently only audio-recording). You can look at [this repository](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder); where  "[`AudioStreamRecorder/MediaRecorder.js`](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder/blob/master/AudioStreamRecorder/MediaRecorder.js)" is exactly what you want. [`Try the demo`](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/MediaStreamRecorder/demos/audio-recorder.html).

Another example "[`AudioVideoRecorder`](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/AudioVideoRecorder)" is also available. [`Try the demo`](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/AudioVideoRecorder/).

Comment: The example that you have given does not seem to work in firefox.

Comment: I am able to get the recording feature on nightly. I was looking for the normal firefox. Anyway firefox is releasing its support for AudioContext in its next release according to its website. Life will be simpler then! Thanks for the info.